# Can I reduce this reoccurring pattern in my Java class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, refactoring

I have the following interface:

```
public interface Gravy {

     public List<Giblet> getGiblets();
     public Giblet getGiblet(String id);
     public int getNumGiblets();
     public void addGiblet();
     public void removeGiblet(Giblet giblet);

     public List<Carrot> getCarrots();
     public Carrot getCarrot(String id);
     public int getNumCarrots();
     public void addCarrot();
     public void removeCarrot(Carrot carrot);

     public List<Gravy> getGravies();
     public Gravy getGravy(String id);
     public int getNumGravies();
     public void addGravy();
     public void removeGravy(Gravy gravy);

}
```

As you can see, I have a reoccurring pattern in my `Gravy`. A `Gravy` object can contain giblets, carrots, and other (smaller) gravies. All of which can be added to, removed from, or queried.

Two things to note:

1. `Carrot`s and `Giblet`s have a bit in common with each other, but both differ vastly from `Gravy`s.
2. I may need to add more items later on (thus the need for a refactoring)...

Is it possible to reduce the above code so that the "verbs" are only written once?

Comment: use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on how similar you consider the group of functionality. For example, if the group of functionality can be considered as a something in itself, e.g. a set of ingredients, then you could do the following:

```
public interface Ingredient<T> {
     public List<T> getAll();
     public T get(String id);
     public int size();
     public void add(T item);
     public void remove(T item);
}

public interface Gravy {
     public Ingredient<Giblet> getGiblets();
     public Ingredient<Carrot> getCarrots();
     public Ingredient<Gravy> getGravies();
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this is quite nice.